# Mailbox migration fails from Exchange 2016 to 2019

Tags: email, exchange, exchange-migration

I'm doing an Exchange upgrade from 2016 to 2019 and started having migration failures on a number of mailboxes. I went from 2010 to 2016 with no issues. The first time I started the migration (using EMS commands) I made a rookie mistake and the hard drive filled with logs. I fixed that issue and managed to get a few more mailboxes moved. Now any mailbox over 1GB, about 15 left, fails between 24-29% with the following error. I've been researching this for weeks and can only find references to C# coding and applications.

Request '[local domain].local/Users/[alias]' (e18b4061-ebc3-4f67-84b9-30810b7c4339) failed.
Error code: -2146233088
The call to 'net.tcp://exchange2016.[local domain].local/Microsoft.Exchange.MailboxReplicationService.ProxyService Exchange2016.[local domain].local (15.1.1913.5 caps:0FFD6FFFBF5FFFFFCB07FFFF)' failed. Error details: The formatter threw an exception while trying to deserialize the message: There was an error while trying to deserialize parameter http://tempuri.org/:IMailbox_ExportMessagesResult. The InnerException message was 'There was an error deserializing the object of type Microsoft.Exchange.MailboxReplicationService.DataExportBatch. The maximum array length quota (35000000) has been exceeded while reading XML data. This quota may be increased by changing the MaxArrayLength property on the XmlDictionaryReaderQuotas object used when creating the XML reader.'.  Please see InnerException for more details. --> There was an error deserializing the object of type Microsoft.Exchange.MailboxReplicationService.DataExportBatch. The maximum array length quota (35000000) has been exceeded while reading XML data. This quota may be increased by changing the MaxArrayLength property on the XmlDictionaryReaderQuotas object used when creating the XML reader. --> The maximum array length quota (35000000) has been exceeded while reading XML data. This quota may be increased by changing the MaxArrayLength property on the XmlDictionaryReaderQuotas object used when creating the XML reader.. --> The formatter threw an exception while trying to deserialize the message: There was an error while trying to deserialize parameter http://tempuri.org/:IMailbox_ExportMessagesResult. The InnerException message was 'There was an error deserializing the object of type Microsoft.Exchange.MailboxReplicationService.DataExportBatch. The maximum array length quota (35000000) has been exceeded while reading XML data. This quota may be increased by changing the MaxArrayLength property on the XmlDictionaryReaderQuotas object used when creating the XML reader.'.  Please see InnerException for more details. --> There was an error deserializing the object of type Microsoft.Exchange.MailboxReplicationService.DataExportBatch. The maximum array length quota (35000000) has been exceeded while reading XML data. This quota may be increased by changing the MaxArrayLength property on the XmlDictionaryReaderQuotas object used when creating the XML reader. --> The maximum array length quota (35000000) has been exceeded while reading XML data. This quota may be increased by changing the MaxArrayLength property on the XmlDictionaryReaderQuotas object used when creating the XML reader.

### Context:

Operation: IMailbox.ExportMessages
Operation: IMailbox.ExportMessages
OperationSide: Source
e18b4061-ebc3-4f67-84b9-30810b7c4339 (Primary)
Flags: SkipItemValidation

### PropTags: (null)

> > > > Scheduled WorkItems: EnumerateFolderMessages(P:288,R:1,S:0,C:15); EnumerateFolderMessages(P:305,R:0,S:0,C:12,Cnt=6); WriteFolderMessages(P:2,R:0,S:0,C:93); EnumerateFolderMessages(P:473,R:0,S:0,C:12,Cnt=7); WriteFolderMessages(P:0,R:0,S:0,C:49); EnumerateFolderMessages(P:598,R:0,S:0,C:14); EnumerateFolderMessages(P:614,R:0,S:0,C:13,Cnt=4); WriteFolderMessages(P:2,R:0,S:0,C:1818); EnumerateFolderMessages(P:2560,R:0,S:0,C:343); WriteFolderMessages(P:2,R:0,S:0,C:1806,Cnt=5)

Here's what I've tried to fix it:

- setting a static bad limit, started at 100 and incremented to 3000.
  no change.
- created a new mailbox database and tried migrating to
  that. no change.
- added a new data drive to the virtual machine, new
  mailbox database on the new drive. no change.
- tried single and bulk migrations. no change.

any idea how to get past this? Or any idea what file Microsoft.Exchange.MailboxReplicationService.DataExportBatch is in so I can change the buffer size?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to the similar thread "**[Getting Error in Mailbox Migration from Exchange 2013 to 2016 for some users](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/f9468e70-67ee-4954-aa8a-91f8163f3636/getting-error-in-mailbox-migration-from-exchange-2013-to-2016-for-some-users?forum=exchangesvradmin)**" and the error "**The maximum array length quota (35000000) has been exceeded while reading XML data.** ", the migration issue could be caused by exceeding the quota(**maxArrayLength**).

You could try to increase the quota in the xml file **MsExchangeMailboxReplication.exe.config**(**C:\Program Files\Microsoft\Exchange Server\V15\Bin\MsExchangeMailboxReplication.exe.config**), then migrate the remaining 15 mailboxes again to check the result. To revert the changes easily, you could backup the original quotas.

Comment: that fixed the first problem, but now I get a TransientFailureSource error when moving and there's nothing in the even logs. Is this related or a different issue?

Comment: I'm not sure if the "TransientFailureSource" error is related with the first problem, but you could run the command " Get-MoveRequestStatistics -Identity <MailboxName> | fl  *failure *, Report " to see if there are some errors in the result. (Because the format rule in the reply text, I couldn't use two multiplication signs, you need remove the blank character after the parameter "failure")

Comment: I managed to find the error using the GUI to migrate the mailbox. Now it's an issue with MaxReceivedMessageSize. I increased it incrementally, restarting the Mailbox Migration service each time and it's still not enough.  Right now the value is at 99999999, any higher and the service won't start. I'm thinking there's a different issue here than the buffer sizes?

Comment: I used the | fl *failure *, Report command and get this TotalTransientFailureDuration : 00:00:00
FailureCode                   : -2146233088
FailureType                   : CommunicationErrorPermanentException
FailureSide                   : Source
FailureTimestamp              : 5/12/2020 1:59:48 PM
LastFailure                   :
Report                        :

Comment: marking this as the answer. This, combined with some other solutions fixed the problem and I can finish transferring mailboxes. Thank you.